# Java: Is it possible to hide a superinterface from the clients of its implementing class?

Tags: java, design-patterns

Let's take a look at the following code:

```
package A;

public interface MySuperInterface{
enum MyENUM { ...}
}

public class MyImplementingClass implements MySuperInterface{
public void someFunction(MyENUM e);
}
```

---

```
package B;

import A.MyImplementingClass;

public class MyClientClass{
MyImplementingClass mic = new MyImplementingClass();
mic.someFunction( /* here's my question. I need MyClientClass to know only about MyImplementingClass and nothing about MySuperInterface */);
}
```

As you can see above, in order to use `someFunction()`, `MyClientClass` needs to know about a (ENUM) type  called `MyENUM` which is defined inside `MySuperInterface`. My question is, is it possible to design `MyClientClass` to know **only** about `MyImplementingClass` and **nothing** about `MySuperInterface`?

In other words, `MyClientClass` doesn't need to import `MySuperInterface`.

**Update** This code is for illustration only. The reason why I am asking this is to know about Maximum Encapsulation. In other words, I want to know if it's possible that a client can use a Class without knowing ***anything*** about its ancestors (superinterfaces, superclasses).

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is. To use a method, you must know the type of its parameters.

Comment: If clients shouldn't know about the interface, what is the reason for having MyImplementingClass implement it? Can you explain more about the motivation for this question?

Comment: How do implementers of `MyClientClass` know the members of `MyENUM`? Should he at least need to refer to the `MySuperInterface` documentation?

Comment: Hiding an abstraction to expose an implementation is the opposite of what Information Hiding aims to achieve in OOP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All static members of `MySuperInterface` are also available on `MyImplementingClass`, so your client code can just do this:

```
mic.someFunction(MyImplementingClass.MyENUM.FOO)
```

Comment: So, if, for example, MyClientClass is in another package, does it need to import MySuperInterface?

Comment: No, it does not need to import the super interface.